# Modularizar aplicación de AngularJs en diferentes archivos

Tags: angularjs

Tengo una aplicación creada con Angular 1.6.3, con todos los controllers y configuraciones en un solo archivo, estoy tratando de modularizar el código. Pero no logro hacerla funcionar.

Aquí esta el código completo **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JyWCvJQ9NsUWBWWwlqAC?p=preview)**

---

Cree una archivo **app.module.js** para definir los módulos como dependencias

```
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', [
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'ngAnimate',
            'myAppRouter',
            'ngRoute',
            //Los controllers se deben llamar aquí?
            'myApp.clientController',
            'myApp.adminController'
        ]);
```

Un archivo **app.routes.js** para implementar $stateProvider

```
angular
    .module('myAppRouter', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('client', {
                    url: '/client',
                    templateUrl: 'client.html',
                    controller:         'myApp.clientController'
                }).state('admin', {
                    url: '/admin',
                    templateUrl: 'admin.html',
                    controller: 'myApp.adminController'
                });
        }
    ]);
```

Un **controller**

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('myApp.clientController', ['$scope'], clientController);

function clientController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Petter';
}
```

y el **index.html**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/client">Client</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.module.js"></script>
```

1. Qué esta mal en el código, Por qué no funciona?
2. No es el enfoque más adecuado para que el código este separado?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate tienes varios problemas, para ello modifique algunos detalles en tu plunker. Aquí esta el otro **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/usJPJeJgPTX2m901cSnh?p=preview)**

Comenzando por **app.module.js**, efectivamente los controladores no van allí, puesto que estos son componentes del modulo y no un modulo propiamente que sea una dependencia allí. Por lo que ellos ya están en el modulo **myApp**.

Por otro lado el mayor de los problemas que habia era a diferencia del **app.module.js**, ninguno de los demás archivos javascript están cargados en tu pagina como scripts, por lo cual no los consigue. Eso incluye a la dependencia al modulo **ui-route**. Debe estar todos los archivos, para esto te recomiendo en vez de colocar todos unos a uno revisar algo de un automatizador de tarea, tales como **grunt** o **gulp**, sobre **nodeJS**. Te dejo un ejemplo típico para de como se recogen todos los archivos javascript de tu app y como los crea en un solo archivo minificado y ofuscado en otra carpeta.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('component',function(){
    gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){console.log(e);}))
        .pipe(concat('app-bundle.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/assets/js'));
});
```

Por ultimo, puede crear ciertas configuraciones en archivos distintos, y no necesariamente tener que crear un nuevo modulo por cada uno. Es decir el archivo **app.routes.js** pudiera tener el mismo nombre de modulo **myApp**, y no tendrías que cargarlo como dependencia en el archivo de módulos.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo a aclarar varias dudas que tenía, pero surgieron otras tres:
1-En el plunker que editaste, agregar **angular-ui-router.min.js**, es para poder implementar stateProvider?
2- Lo de _**app.routes.js** pudiera tener el mismo nombre de módulo **myApp**_ seria hacer: ``angular.module(' myApp ', ['ui.router'])`` ?
3- Lo más importante, ¿Por qué no sirven los controllers?, parece como que no los carga, muestra Error: [ng:areq] http:// errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/ng/areq?p0=myApp.clientController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string

Comment: Hola @bryannsi, 1. Según tu vista y según **app.routes.js** tu dependencia era esa. De hecho no es necesaria ngRoute como dependencia. 2. si, pero como te comente, es opcional, en plunker lo deje con otro modulo. 3. Habia un detalle en la declaracion del controlador, estaba `.controller('myApp.adminController', ['$scope'], adminController);` y deberia ser `.controller('myApp.adminController', ['$scope', adminController]);`